# R: Installing MonetDBLite under Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: r, ubuntu-14.04, survey, monetdb, monetdblite

I try to use MonetDBLite for R to [analyze survey data for free](http://www.asdfree.com/) on an Ubuntu 14.04 OS.

Installing *MonetDBLite* from source via

```
install.packages("MonetDBLite",
                 repos=c("http://dev.monetdb.org/Assets/R/",
                         "http://cran.rstudio.com/"),
                 type="source")
```

results in the following error.

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcurl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -luuid
```

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out

- *R needs to be above version 3.2* and
- the *following packages need to be installed*: `libcurl4-openssl-dev liblzma-dev uuid-dev`

Credit goes to [Hannes Mühleisen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2652376/hannes-m%C3%BChleisen) for basically sorting this out.

(https://www.monetdb.org/blog/monetdblite-r)

Comment: Updated MonetDBLite so adding the extra packages is no longer required.